# Emberj js onclick fail performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I'm trying to show a gif(loading animation) when I click over a button inside of form on login. When is loged right  then I hide the gif.

What happen, When I click the button it's take some seconds but, dont show nothing.

This is the simple code of the handlerbars:

```html
 <div data-role="page">  

      <!-- This is div  global because I need it ,in another views-->
      <div class="loading"></div>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
                <div id="logo"></div>
                {{#if error}}
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                     {{error-message}}
                  </div>
                {{/if}}


                {{#if render}}
                  <div class="div-middle">
                        <label class="lab">Ingrese su PIN</label>
                        {{input placeholder="Ingrese su PIN" class="field-extra form-box"  type="password" valueBinding="pin"}}
                        {{#unless fail  }}
                          <div class="alert alert-danger font-extra form-box field-extra">
                             {{failMessage}}
                          </div>
                        {{/unless}}
                       <button id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success btn-extra form-box" {{action 'login' }}>Iniciar sesión</button>
                  </div>
                {{/if}}
                {{outlet}}
      </script>  
</div>
```

Well, I've a div with class loading , I put the image inside of this div.
So when beggining the IndexController I hide the div, but when is clicked the button I show the div, and I pretend stop the show image when I init another Controller

```js
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   init: function()
   {
      //hide the image until is clicked the button
      $('.loading').hide();
   },
   actions:{
       login:function(){
          $('.loading').show();
          if( isOK() ){
             this.transitionToRoute('operador.lectura');
          }
       }
   }
});
```

When is redirected to this controller I hide the Image

```js
App.OperadorLecturaController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   init:function()
   {
      $('.loading').hide();
   }
});
```

The trouble is that I never see that show/hide effect,

why occurs this, and how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest looking this example from the cookbook http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/helpers_and_components/spin_button_for_asynchronous_actions/.

Comment: Not works , I don't know what happen, some times show something another time not works, I use a web service inside of method `isOK()`

Comment: Can you recreate this issue in jsbin?